# How to configure DLQ for a failed message using Spring Boot jmsListener?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jms

Please guide me as how to configure a DLQ for the failed message processing in Spring Boot JMS. I would like to send the failed messages to DLQ based on the error type. Ex, business error - send to DLQ, technical error - discard...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It should be through the JMS provider, in my case I had to configure a Backout queue for the listener queue and DLQ at the queue manager level